# Hi, I cant seem to print the results of a program that will compare three circles size using DrawingPanel

Tags: java, if-statement, drawing, system.out

Hi beginner programer here I need help with printing the results for this program. I have already created a method to compare the circles radius, however I would like to include the color of the circles compared when I print the results, I however cant seem to be able to do that as shown by the (?). how can i print a different color?

ex: when i compare green and red 
 "The green circle is bigger than the red circle"
 to when i compare green to blue
 "The green circle is smaller than the blue circle"

```
 //class
 // main method
    //asked for input and stored values in variable for r1, x1, y1
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval(x1-r1, y1-r1, r1*2, r1*2);
   //asked for input and stored values in variable for r2, x2, y2
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(x2-r2, y2-r2, r2*2, r2*2);

    //asked for input and stored values in variable for r3, x3, y3
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval(x3-r3, y3-r3, r3*2, r3*2); 
    int compare = size(r1, r2);
    result1(compare);
    compare = size(r1, r3);
    result1(compare);
    compare = size(r2, r3);
    result1(compare);


public static int size(int r1, int r2){
    if(r1 < r2){
      return -1;
    }else if( r1 == r2){
      return 0;
    }else{
      return 1;
    }
  }
   public static void result1(int n){
    if (n == -1){
      System.out.println("The " + ? + "cirlce is smaller than the " + ? + "circle.");
    }else if(n == 0){
      System.out.println("The " + ? + "circle is the same size as the " + ? + "cirle.");
    }else{
      System.out.println("The " + ? + "circle is bigger than the " + ? + "circle");
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class circle, like

```
public class MyCircle {
    int radius;
    Color color;

    public MyCircle(int radius, Color color) {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
    }

    //Getter Setter...
    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Create a method to get the color name as string

```
public static String getColorAsName(MyCircle circle) {
    String colorName = null;
    if (circle.getColor().equals(Color.BLACK)) {
        colorName = "BLACK";
    } else if(circle.getColor().equals(Color.RED)) {
        colorName = "RED";
    }
    ...

    return colorName;
}
```

Then create circle objects, like

```
MyCircle c1 = new Circle(r1, Color.GREEN)
MyCircle c2 = new Circle(r2, Color.GREEN)
etc...
```

Using getter-setter you can update the attributes when needed.

Change method

```
public static void result1(int n){
```

to

```
public static void result1(int n, MyCircle firstCircle, MyCircle lastCircle){
    if (n == -1){
        System.out.println("The " + getColorAsName(firstCircle) + " cirlce is smaller than the " + getColorAsName(lastCircle) + " circle.");
...
```

and call `result1()` like:

```
result1(compare, c1, c2);
...
```

Comment: @mazharul Thanks that seems to have work i did however need to change the last 2 parameters because it would print the size instead of color.

Comment: DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(400, 300);
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();

Comment: @Johan14th if the answer is helpful, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a method like this:

```
public static void result1(int number, int radius1, int radius2){
    // some code
}
```